# Multiple plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that draws two superimposed plots from a two-dimensional list using matplotlib:

```
for day in days:

    # Draw a green triangle
    plt.plot(day[0], len(day[1] * 100), 'g^')

    # Draw red dots
    for hour in day[1]:
        plt.plot(day[0], hour, 'ro')
```

This results in a plot like the following:

[image]

But I'd like the triangles to be connected with solid lines so that the evolution along the X-axis is seen more clearly. No matter what I replace 'g^' with I can't seem to draw solid lines here. How is this supposed to be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you really want to loop through the data and plot it one-by-one you could do the following:

```python
green_triangles,_ = plt.plot([],[],'g^')#Could be that you need 'g^-'. Can't test it now
for day in days:

    # Draw a green triangle
    X = np.append(green_triangles.get_xdata(), day[0])
    Y = np.append(green_triangles.get_ydata(), len(day[1] * 100))             
    green_triangles.set_xdata(X)
    green_triangles.set_ydata(Y)

    # Draw red dots
    for hour in day[1]:
        plt.plot(day[0], hour, 'ro')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do two lines to make the triangles connected, it is not beautiful, but works:

```
# Draw a green triangles, as you said:
plt.plot(day[0], len(day[1] * 100), 'g^')
# another line to draw the green line:
plt.plot(day[0], len(day[1] * 100), 'g')
```

Or, after reading [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), you can write:

```
plt.plot(day[0], len(day[1] * 100), linestyle='solid', marker='^', color='g')
```

Comment: Thank you? I have read the documentation regarding plot formatting, but I couldn't get it to work, that's why I asked here... This doesn't work either (I only get the triangles, as in the screen capture above). Can't seem to properly format my code in the comment, but I tried both your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
plt.plot(day[0], len(day[1] * 100), 'g^')
```

with

```
plt.plot(day[0], len(day[1] * 100), '-g^')
```

Notice the additional `-` in the second line.

Comment: Not working either. Could this be a Python version or OS problem (I'm on Mac OS 10.12, Python 3.5.2, mathplotlib freshly installed yesterday from repository)?